# JDBI I want to bulk update using some thing like bulk insert with creating object

Tags: batch-file, jdbi, batch-updates, bulkupdate

I have to batch update using JDBI same like batch insert with out creating object.Any one know the process please let me know .Remember not using object like mapping column to object's attribute

Answer (score 4):

Use argument binding.
Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```java
PreparedBatch insertBatch = handle.prepareBatch("INSERT INTO foo.bar (baz) VALUES (:bazArgument)");

//assume what you want to insert is stored in a List<String> bazes
for (String st : bazes) {
    insertBatch.bind("bazArgument", st).add();
}

int[] countArray = insertBatch.execute();
```

You can extend it for more variables etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example for a batch operation with JDBI and MySQL database. The table is of InnoDB type.

```
package com.zetcode;

import org.skife.jdbi.v2.Batch;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.DBI;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.Handle;

public class JDBIEx6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DBI dbi = new DBI("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb",
                "testuser", "test623");

        Handle handle = dbi.open();
        Batch batch = handle.createBatch();

        batch.add("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Friends");
        batch.add("CREATE TABLE Friends(Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT)");
        batch.add("INSERT INTO Friends(Name) VALUES ('Monika')");
        batch.add("INSERT INTO Friends(Name) VALUES ('Tom')");
        batch.add("INSERT INTO Friends(Name) VALUES ('Jane')");
        batch.add("INSERT INTO Friends(Name) VALUES ('Robert')");

        batch.execute();
    }
}
```

The following is a Maven POM file for the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.zetcode</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDBIEx6</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>2.73</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>    
</project>
```

You can learn more about JDBI from my [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/jdbi/).

Comment: This is not the right solution of my problem , Think if i have to insert/update  3000 records then ?